# Will deselected updates show up again?

Tags: update-manager

I think I mistakenly unchecked a box before installing updates. So the updates were installed, but one was skipped, because I’d unintentionally deselected it. Will Ubuntu offer me that update again, or will it remember that I deselected it and not show it again? Is there any way to check whether I’m missing any updates?

I tried running an update in the Terminal, and it didn’t show anything.

```
timothy@timothy-Vostro-220-Series:~$ sudo apt-get update
...

timothy@timothy-Vostro-220-Series:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

- It’s possible that I *didn’t* deselect an update. I’m not sure. I *think* I did. As I said, it was a mistake.
- It’s possible that I *did* deselect an update, and that update has since been offered to me again and installed in a subsequent batch of updates.
- It’s possible that I *did* deselect an update, and Ubuntu is remembering that I deselected it, and not offering it to me again.

For what it’s worth, I think it was a kernel update.

Comment: Is there anything useful in /var/log/dpkg.log?

Comment: It's a big file. Anything in particular I should look for? or grep for?

Comment: Thanks, @Jos. That shows nothing, which suggests I have everything (so, either the first or the second of my two possibilities above). Want to rewrite that as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-mark showhold`.

No output means no packages are on hold. See [PinningHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) in the Ubuntu documentation.